# updating a relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model that has a relationship like this

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
public function latestUrlStatus(){
    return $this->hasOne(UrlStatus::class)->latest();
}
```

from my controller i can save from `many to many relationship` like this (SUCCESS NO PROBLEM)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $updateUrl = Url::findOrFail($id);
    $updateUrl->url = $request->input('url');
    $updateUrl->description = $request->input('description');
    $updateUrl->users()->sync(array_pluck($request->input('selectedTags'), 'id'));
    $updateUrl->save();

        if($updateUrl){
            return new UrlsResource($updateUrl);
        }
}
```

but when i add this code to save from another relation

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $updateUrl = Url::findOrFail($id);
    $updateUrl->url = $request->input('url');
    $updateUrl->description = $request->input('description');
    $updateUrl->users()->sync(array_pluck($request->input('selectedTags'), 'id'));
    $updateUrl->save();

    //THIS CODE UP TO LAST
    $httpCode = check_http_header($request->input('url'));
    $status = "UP";

    $url = Url::with('latestUrlStatus','users')->findOrfail($id);
    $updateUrl->latestUrlStatus()->status_code = $httpCode;
    $updateUrl->latestUrlStatus()->status = $status;
    $updateUrl->push();
    if($updateUrl){
       return new UrlsResource($updateUrl);
    }
}
```

it doesnt update the latest url status. I'm sorry just new to framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus()` to `$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus` and try

Comment: lol it is okay now

Comment: put it on answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in your update code `$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus()` to `$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus` like this

```
$updateUrl = Url::with('latestUrlStatus','users')->findOrfail($id);
$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus->status_code = $httpCode;
$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus->status = $status;
$updateUrl->push();
if($updateUrl){
   return new UrlsResource($updateUrl);
}
```

`$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus()` return query `Builder` instance, where has `$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus` return `UrlStatus` instance, thats what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus()->save()
```

instead of

```
$updateUrl->push();
```

`$updateUrl->push` saves a model ($updateUrl) and all it's relations. If it doesn't work and `$updateUrl->latestUrlStatus->save()` works, then you know that `$updateUrl` just doesnt recognize `->latestUrlStatus()` as a relation, probably because of you using the function method `latestUrlStatus()`, to access the submodel, not the magic method `->latestUrlStatus`